# Not sure how to fix builtin.TypeError's

Tags: python

Hey I'm having two errors when I type drink and enter the amount of sugar I get "builtins.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" and when I type AlcoholicDrink and amount of sugar and alcohol I get "builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly". I'm still learn to code so I'm not good with errors any help is appreciated!

```
class Drink:
    def __init__(self, sugar):
        self.sugar = sugar

    def numberOfCalories(self):
        return 3.87 * sugar

class AlcoholicDrink(Drink):
    def __init__(self, alcohol, sugar):
        super().__init__(sugar)       
        self.alcohol  = alcohol

    def numberOfCalories(self):
        if self.alcohol > 0:
            return self.alcohol * 7.0 + self.sugar
        else:
            super().numberOfCalories()

choice = input('What would you like to drink?(Drink or AlcoholicDrink)  ')

if (choice == 'AlcoholicDrink'):

    sugar = float(input('How much sugar is in your drink? '))
    alcohol = float(input('How much alcohol is in your drink? '))
    userDrink = AlcoholicDrink(sugar, alcohol)

elif (choice == 'Drink'):

    sugar = float(input('how much sugar is in your drink? '))
    userDrink = Drink(sugar)

print ('Your amount of calories are ' + (userDrink.numberOfCalories()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `'str' object is not callable` error: you have a `class Drink` and then you assign `Drink = input(...)`. The latter is overwriting the former. Python does not have separate buckets for functions, classes, and strings. Use unique variable names to avoid this problem.

For the `Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly` error: the last `print()` call is trying to concatenate (with `+`) a `str`, `'Your amount of calories are '`, with a `float`, `userDrink.numberOfCalories()`. You have a few options for that:

Convert the `float` to a `str`:

```
print('Your amount of calories are ' +  str(userDrink.numberOfCalories()))
```

Pass multiple arguments to the `print()` call:

```
print('Your amount of calories are',  userDrink.numberOfCalories())
```

Use string formatting:

```
print('Your amount of calories are {}'.format(userDrink.numberOfCalories()))
```

Use old string formatting (not recommended, as it's deprecated in favor of the newer string formatting above):

```
print('Your amount of calories are %f' % userDrink.numberOfCalories())
```

Comment: @bradmonster - Sorry I didn't notice your mention of the other error. I've added a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

You hid the Drink class with a local variable of the same name.  Make that line

```
Drink = input('What would you like to drink?(Drink or AlcoholicDrink)  ')
```

into

```
choice = input('What would you like to drink?(Drink or AlcoholicDrink)  ')
```

and change all the other references accordingly:

```
if (choice == 'AlcoholicDrink'):

    sugar = float(input('How much sugar is in your drink? '))
    alcohol = float(input('How much alcohol is in your drink? '))
    userDrink = AlcoholicDrink(sugar, alcohol)

elif (choice == 'Drink'):

    sugar = float(input('how much sugar is in your drink? '))
    userDrink = Drink(sugar)

print ('Your amount of calories are ' + (userDrink.numberOfCalories()))
```

Comment: I have applied your suggestion but the same errors are still coming up.

Comment: Please see the help/mcve page.  Among other things, post the current code and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, your "Drink" variable is actually referencing the class Drink that you created before. Conventionally variables begin with a lower case letter and classes being with a capital letter.  Adopting these conventions can help you avoid issues like this in the future.

Changing this to a different name will help resolve your issues!

Read this for more python conventions:

[Proper Python Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I did apply changes that are visible above but still exact same errors